# Select Checkbox inside span using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a checkbox within a span container. How can I get the type and productid using Javascript?

Here's the innerHTML:

```
<span productid="6">
    <input id="MainContent_chk8" name="ctl00$MainContent$chk8" type="checkbox">
    <label for="MainContent_chk8">Test6</label>
</span>
```

Comment: Just a tip, use `data-*` for custom attributes to avoid failing HTML validation

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something as simple as this:

```
var check = document.getElementById("MainContent_chk8"),
    productId = check.parentNode.getAttribute("productid");
```

Of course, this implies that you should know the `id` of the checkbox in advance - which may not be the case, as that seems to be a checkbox generated by the server.

It also implies that you are certain that the parent of the checkbox has the attribute you're looking for.

It may help if you quote more of your code. Your question is tagget "asp.net", so I guess this HTML snippet is generated by some ASP.NET code.

Comment: yes HTML snippet is generated by ASP.NET Code what i doing is adding custom attribute to checkbox(productid).In client side javascipt i write code var inputElements = document.getElementsByTagName('span'); and makes a loop. Thanks for your quick response

Comment: Got Solution.Thanks Max